# Spartan 6 external RAM store

Tags: vhdl, fpga, ram, spartan

I have to store values to external RAM's connected with FPGA. From what I have researched, there is a way using MIG in ISE. Should I design using ISE or use Microblaze on XPS ?

Comment: That decision is up to you. We can't tell you what to do…

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application you want to use it for and your skill level.

Designer skill level: 
If you are a beginner to FPGA's or you have a more software background i would suggest to try to run a simple example in EDK. If you are familiar with RTL design in Verilog or VHDL you can instantiate the MIG core.

Application depended considerations:

1. performance: if you want to achieve very high performance you are morel likely to achieve that using the ISE + MIG toolflow.
2. area: instantiating a MicroBlaze soft-CPU requires some resources in your device. If you have plenty of space it is no big deal but if you need a lot of other logic in a small Spartan6 you might want to use plain RTL to optimize your resource utilization.